# linking ggplot axis text to different pages in rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

related to this question: [Hyperlinking text in a ggplot2 visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259826/hyperlinking-text-in-a-ggplot2-visualization/42262407)

Is it possible for each link to reference a different page of the PDF being rendered instead of an external URL?

Comment: Interesting question, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I was able to link the text on the axis to pages or headers (just change the URL in the linked question to `pdf_name#page=1` for example to link to first page) however this generates an SVG and haven't been able to include that into the rmarkdown.